# Unable to load system.core when including oxyplot in WPF window XAML

Tags: visual-studio-2012, designer

I get the following error in the designer when trying to include the oxyplot component.

```
Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteException
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at OxyPlot.PlotModel.Update(Boolean updateData)
   at OxyPlot.Wpf.Plot.UpdateModel(Boolean updateData) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f48330714bade418\Source\OxyPlot.Wpf\Plot.cs:line 1493
   at OxyPlot.Wpf.Plot.UpdateModelAndVisuals(Boolean updateData) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f48330714bade418\Source\OxyPlot.Wpf\Plot.cs:line 1506
   at OxyPlot.Wpf.Plot.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeBounds) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f48330714bade418\Source\OxyPlot.Wpf\Plot.cs:line 689
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
   at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateLayout()
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.SetLayoutSize()
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisualInternal(Visual value)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisual(Visual value)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteUIElement.<>c__DisplayClass12.<Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteUIElement.CreateContent>b__11()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.<>c__DisplayClass16`1.<MarshalIn>b__15()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.Invoke(Boolean waitingInExternalCall)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.InvokeCall(Call call)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.ProcessQueue(CallQueue queue)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.ProcessInboundAsyncQueue(Int32 identity)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.ProcessMessage(Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, Boolean elevatedQuery, Boolean& handled)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.OnWindowMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.MessageOnlyHwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolationProcess.RunApplication()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolationProcess.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Main>b__0()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

However I can see in the references that System.Core is included though the error says it wants version `2.0.5.0` and the version of System.Core the library is using is `4.0.0.0`. I have installed OxyPlot via Nuget. Is there a problem with the Nuget package?

Answer (score 3):

This was a case of RTFM. There are two Nuget packages. The one I installed was the PCL version. To use the designer one must install the non PCL version of the WPF nuget package.

Comment: I had the same issue, but couldn't find the non-PCL version of OxyPlot on the GUI version of Nuget.  Run the command `Install-Package OxyPlot.Wpf_NoPCL -Version 2013.1.52.1` through the package manager console instead.

Comment: It does not work for me too. I've installed through NuGet and via the command above, but I have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with a project on one of my machines. It seems to be an environmental issue. I've repaired Visual Studio installation and the problem was gone.