# Draw line charts in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, charts

In my WPF application I need to draw some dynamic line chart, that receives data from a background process and can be updated at runtime. I need also that graph is not static but moves while data arrives from other process.

I've read about OxyPlot and DynamicDataDisplay but the first does not work for me (see [Unable to load system.core when including oxyplot in WPF window XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143785/unable-to-load-system-core-when-including-oxyplot-in-wpf-window-xaml)) and the second has no documentation to explain how to use it.
Anybody knows another library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telerik, DevExpress and Xceed all have WPF charting libraries tho' they are all paid for annual licenses.

In terms of open source, you've basically got OxyPlot or the WPF Toolkit Charting 4.0 (where there is a properly ported to .NET 4.0 and including Stacked chart series) at http://dlaa.me/blog/post/9910837

Comment: I'm looking for Open Source libraries. OxyPlot, as written above, does not work for me. I will have a look at Toolkit Charting.

Comment: WPF Toolkit is the best option as it's MVVM compatible - OxyPlot is decidedly procedural (no binding support), even tho' you can practically control every aspect of a plot.

Comment: Unfortunately WPF Toolkit does not allow to have a dynamic chart, like OxyPlot does...and I need that one...

Comment: It does, if you're prepared to write a wrapping UserControl around it which I did.

Comment: Can you explain me how to do it?

Comment: Sure. Create a user control with an ICollectionChanged bindable collection property which accepts a Series item. The user control should also have a single named Chart control in it. When you receive notifications from the collection, add/remove/replace the Series item in the Chart controls Series property. Easy-peasy. ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66212/discussion-between-francescods-and-toadflakz).

Comment: After chatting and using opensource components, I've noticed that OxyPlot does not work (it gaves me an error when I add it in XAML) and WPF Toolkit does not work too (maybe it has some conflicts with other references in my project, cause in a brand new project it works). Are there other open source components useful?